# mysql row_number() performance

Tags: mysql, rank, groupwise-maximum

Sorry. This is a rewritten question because there was no answer.

I changed it from rank() to row_number() because the same rank is not needed.

---

I'm currently working on a query, but I'm not getting the speed so I'm asking a question.

What I want to find is 'count the most names in each category by DataID'.

Data_Category {
id : INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
DataId: INT,
name: varchar2(200),
category: varchar2(200)
}

and it is possible to input in duplicate.

```
select dataId, name, category, count(*) as cnt
, row_number() over (partition by dataId, category order by count(*) desc) as "ranking"
from data_category
group by dataId, name, category
```

In the above query, there is a difference in speed with and without the rank part.

If there is no row_number, it takes 0.0053, and if there is, it takes 0.5 seconds.
The result is about 260,000 rows.

```
select *, row_number() over (partition by A.dataId, A.category order by cnt desc) as "ranking"
from(
  select dataId, name, category, count(*) as cnt
  from data_category
  group by dataId, name, category
) A
```

The above query also yields almost the same speed. The moment it is wrapped in a select statement, it is slowing down due to the temporary table creation.

The data is about 400,000 cases.

The index is (dataId, category, name) .

I want to extract 5 names with the highest number of names in each category by data ID, but I can't figure out the direction of the query.

And I will create 'view' using this query.
So there are no additional where clause.
After that, I want to use it by joining it with another table.

Even if you don't write a query, I sincerely ask for a simple hint..!

Output:

| dataId | category | name | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cate1 | name1_1 | 1 |
| 1 | cate1 | name1_2 | 2 |
| 1 | cate1 | name1_5 | 3 |
| 1 | cate1 | name1_3 | 4 |
| 1 | cate2 | name2_1 | 1 |
| 1 | cate2 | name2_5 | 2 |
| 1 | cate2 | name2_3 | 3 |
| 2 | cate1 | name3_1 | 1 |
| 2 | cate3 | name3_9 | 1 |

Thank you.

---

Explain

#Query 1-2 : Without rank_row

| id | select_type | table | type | key | rows | filtered | extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | data_cateogory | index | IDX_39ea6497ea9ca40d9e783e | 432344 | 100.00 | Using index; |

#Query 1-1 : With rank_row

| id | select_type | table | type | key | rows | filtered | extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | data_cateogory | index | IDX_39ea6497ea9ca40d9e783e | 432344 | 100.00 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |

Comment: For performance questions it's useful if you include the output of an EXPLAIN.

Comment: Have you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-optimization.html#:~:text=The%20most%20general%20way%20to,aggregate%20functions%20(if%20any).

Comment: @P.Salmon Thanks for the comment. I added explain result. I'll read the links in other comments.

Comment: @P.Salmon It doesn't seem to be a problem with group by. It seems to slow down in the process of sorting by count(*).

Comment: The window function is applied over grouped rowset, i.e. at the moment when the index usage is not available, and aggregated value is used for sorting. By fact this is "double grouping". And the data size is approx. 200-400 Mb, so memory temptable is not applicable. I do not see the way to this query improvement.

Comment: @Akina thank you. It is unfortunate that there is no way to improve it. Or is there any other way to get the rank quickly?

Comment: You do not use any filtering - so pre-calculation may be a solution.

Comment: @Akina What does `pre-calculation` mean? Is it a way to create a table and put the calculated values ​​in advance?

Comment: This means that you create additional table which stores the data obtained by your slow query. You may renew its data by triggers and/or recalculate it completely from event procedure. When you need this data you simply query this table. Of course you may not calculate everything - for example, COUNT() is precalculated whereas RANK() is calculated in the query (and it uses suitable index which is present in this additional table). You loose in disk space but win in execution time.

Comment: @Akina This data is frequently inserted, updated, and deleted. Is it ok to use a trigger?

Comment: Depends on data change type. If the data is altered with small chunks (starting from single row altering and up to ~100-1000 rows per query), and this process is not time-critical, then triggers usage is safe. Anycase this must be tested.

Comment: @Akina After creating the view, I want to use it for search. Speed ​​is important to me. I will create a trigger and test it.

Comment: @Akina Test completed. Creating the trigger directly in mysql was faster than using @AfterInsert(), @BeforeInsert() etc. Thank you!

Comment: What is the sample input for that output?  (I don't understand 'count the most names in each category by DataID'.)

Comment: Please provide the indexes for the table -- `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT...` -- this will give more details.

Answer (score 0):

Does this give you what you need?

```
SELECT DataID, category, COUNT(*)
    FROM t
    GROUP BY DataID, category;
```

Or, if `name` has duplicates, replace `COUNT(*)` by `COUNT(DISTINCT name)`

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I have to count all duplicate data. And the sql you wrote could not get the data I wanted.

Comment: @KunAguero - Duplicate relative to DataID?  To category?  Other?  Give the desired results.

Comment: All data can be duplicated.  I want to extract 5 names with the highest number of names in each category by data ID, but I can't figure out the direction of the query. The desired results are tabulated above.

Comment: @KunAguero - That sounds more like a "groupwise max".  See the tags.